# How do I call a model method into a view?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the difference between two dates in my model into my view to work with.

Model:

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    prop_num = models.IntegerField()
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
        ...
    def date_dif(self):
        return self.start-self.end
```

How do I get date_dif values in my view?

Views:

```
def test(request):
    props = Proposal.objects.all()
    dates = ClosedDate.objects.all()
    for i in props:
        print(i.date_dif)

    context={
        "props":props,
        "dates":dates
    }

    return  render(request,"test.html",context)
```

Comment: Should that not be: `print(i.date_dif())`?

Comment: Ahh yes.. can't believe I forgot that that's needed.

Comment: No worries, mate. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods):

Django models like everything in python is an object, so you can call the custom method after instanciating it, but don't forget that `i.foo` is treated as an attribute and `i.foo()` is a method.

Answer (score -1):

Just to complement the @arcegk answer, the code will be like this:

Model:

```py
class Proposal(models.Model):
   ...
   @classmethod
   def date_dif(self):
      return self.start-self.end
```

`@classmethod` for instantiating objects, and `@staticmethod` for static methods.

In the case of properties, it will be `@property`.